# google api and calendar selection

Tags: python, calendar, google-api

I have a problem with google calendar api.
How can you select which calendar to add an event? It add always to default calendar?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can list the calendars using the `GetOwnCalendarsFeed()` and `GetAllCalendarsFeed()` calls. This will return a list of entries, each of which holds attributes for a given calendar. You need to obtain the calendar's url from the `entry.content.src` attribute, and use this on your `InsertEntry` call:

```
client = calendar.service.CalendarService(email='x', password='y')
feed = client.GetOwnCalendarsFeed()
# map the 'title' -> 'url'
urls = dict((e.title.text, e.content.src) for e in feed.entry)
client.InsertEvent(event, urls['My Calendar'])
```